# Is it possible to do a one-to-many video conference with webrtc

Tags: html, video-streaming, webrtc, video-conferencing

I am wondering if it's possible to create a webapp using **ONLY WEBRTC** that could be able to stream video and audio from one single participant to many (e.g. from the boss to all his employees).

Something like this:
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection/video-broadcasting.html

but in my case i don't want to use a wrapping library like RTCmulticonection.

Comment: Try this instead: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/webrtc-broadcasting

Answer (score 2):

If you have only a few participants, you can just create a peer connection for each.
But you will quickly need a server-side solution like [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/) or [Kurento](http://www.kurento.org/) I think. A browser can't upload a lot of streams, especially with ADSL.
Such media servers also provide more than broadcasting, but also recording and processing like face recognition. You can add more values to your service this way.